# Regular expression - method call with odd number of arguments

Tags: regex

I've got a few method calls in my code:

```
x.method(1)
x.method(1,2)
x.method(1,2,3) # <- FOUND
x.method(1,2,3,4)
x.method(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I need to catch methods with odd number of arguments, and so far I've managed to write such regular expression:
`.method\s?\(([^,)]*,){2}[^,)]*\)`

It is able to find a method call with 3 parameters but I need to find all the calls with odd number of parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to optionally repeat the parts that matches 2 occurrences.

```
\.method\s?\((([^,)]*,){2})*[^,)]*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/guRaL9/1)

If you don't need the capture groups and non capture groups are supported:

```
\.method\s?\((?:(?:[^,)]*,){2})*[^,)]*\)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It solved my issue partially, but there are a few cases that are missed. For example, `x.method(func("TEST"), 1)` will be marked as well, or x.method().

Comment: @xaos_xv In that case you could also exclude matching the opening parenthesis `\.method\s?\((([^,()]*,){2})*[^,()]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/xrP7rM/1

Comment: thanks! Worked like a charm! Do you recommend any places to learn regex? Not gonna lie, I'm pretty bad with it :P. I need to now detect an even number of arguments but will try to do it on my own. Maybe this time I will not ask a stackoverflow question :D

Comment: @xaos_xv There are great resouces like https://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html Also the user [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) has a lot of video's on his youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw/videos